# The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) String, void - help me

Tags: java, eclipse

```
if (rdbtnBrutto.isSelected()) {

    System.out.println("Raumbuch: "+"\r\n"+"1- Raum "+"(Raumbezeichnung= " + tFRaumbe.getText()+", "
                   + "Raumnummer=  "+ tFRaumnu.getText()+")"+"\r\n" +"Raumvolumen= " + Raum.raumvolumen(Double.parseDouble(laengeMauerwerk.getText().toString()),
                Double.parseDouble(laengeStahlbeton.getText().toString()))+" m3"
                   + "\r\n"+"Raumumfang= " + Raum.raumumfang(Double.parseDouble(laengeMauerwerk.getText().toString()), Double.parseDouble(laengeStahlbeton.getText().toString()))+" m"
                   + "\r\n"+ "Raumseitenfläche Brutto= " + Raum.raumflächeohneAbzug (Double.parseDouble(laengeMauerwerk.getText().toString()), Double.parseDouble(laengeStahlbeton.getText().toString()))+" m2");

}
```

Hey there,
I am getting this mistake over and over again. Any advice?

Comment: Please take a few moments and format your code so that others may read it.  In doing so, you might even see the problem about which you are asking here :-)

Comment: One of the method calls whose results you're trying to add together doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell with just this piece of code.

The possible error could be on code "Raumnummer=  "+ tFRaumnu.getText() 
and I suspect that return type of getText() is void. You can check all other return types, it should all be String if you are using + operator.

Comment: It is more likely that `Raum.raumumfang` and/or `Raum.raumflächeohneAbzug` have a return type of `void`.